# Java Implementing a recursive method that traverses tree branches to generate a bitcode (Huffman encoding)

Tags: java, binary-tree, huffman-code

Given a Binary Tree I want to develop a recursive method that finds the bitcode for a specific character given the root of the tree (see diagram)

[image]

Suppose you had a Tree Class where every tree had 4 fields [Left Tree, Right Tree, Left Leaf, Right Leaf] where every branch either led to another tree or a leaf (char value).

```
String result = traverse(root, 'c', ""); //1011

public static String traverse(Tree t, char target, String bitcode){

        String b = bitcode;

        if (t.leftleaf != null){
           if (t.leftleaf == target) {
            b += "0";
           }
        }
        if (t.rightleaf != null){
            if (t.rightleaf == target){ 
            b += "1";       
            }
        }

        if (t.lefttree != null){
            b += "0" + traverse(t.lefttree,target, b);
        }
        if (t.righttree != null){
            b += "1" + traverse(t.righttree,target, b);

        }

        return b;

    }
```

However my method above does not work as expected. How can I rewrite it so it properly shows the bitcode?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not handling the case where target is not found in a subtree. Even if target is not found in left tree, `b += "0" + traverse(t.lefttree,target, b);` will get executed. The same can be said when you traverse the right tree. In fact, your method will traverse the right tree even if target is found in the left tree already. The use of add assignment operator further manifests this problem.

Also note that this function does not require parameter `String bitcode` to work.

```
public static String findBitcode(Tree t, char target){

    // See if target immediately available
    if (t.leftleaf == target) return "0";
    if (t.rightleaf == target) return "1";

    // Search deeper
    String leftResult = findBitcode(t.leftree, target);
    if (leftResult != null) return "0" + leftResult;
    String rightResult = findBitcode(t.righttree, target);
    if (rightResult != null) return "1" + rightResult;

    // Not found
    return null;

}
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question correctly. However, the question is flawed in that this is a horrible way to encode. Searching the tree every time? The OP should instead traverse the entire tree _once_ and build a table indexed by the symbol to return a bit string. Then use that table for encoding. Just like the table shown in the illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You walk the tree from the root towards the leaves when you **decode**, i.e. when you go from binary code to character.

When you **encode** you either have to have an index of character leaves that you can then look up, and then have each tree node point to its parent so that you can generate the code (backwards) when going from the leaf to the root, **or** you can traverse the encoding tree once when constructed and build an encoding table where, for each possible input character, you have the final Huffman code to emit.

Comment: How do you do this if there is no 'parent' for each node but only children? Is it still possible to encode like this?